# Is time depending on the observer in string theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, string-theory, spacetime

I heard that in the theory of relativity the time of an action is depending on the observer. But in string theory, is the time also depending on the observer?

Are strings acting according to the theory of relativity? Or are strings acting in an "objective" time and because of their properties "simulating" the behaviour that we observe and describe using the theory of relativity?

Comment: String theory is a relativistic quantum field theory, nothing fundamental changes about the notion of time.

Comment: @CuriousOne So for a non-physicist like me, the theory of relativity is higher in the hierarchy than the string theory? Then what properties of a string determine its impact on the space-time?

Comment: We are not prioritizing frameworks, but for the last 400 years we didn't have a single theory (with exception of thermodynamics, which is really just the physics version of statistics) that wasn't built on space and time being pre-existing entities. For the last half century, at least, everybody has been talking about abandoning the pre-geometry approach, but nobody has succeeded. String theory hasn't even gone there, yet. There are other models like loop quantum gravity which are trying to build a deeper layer of understanding without pre-existing spacetime, but none of that works, yet.

Comment: @CuriousOne so string theory is not far enough to say whether it is built on simple euclidean space and time or on relativistic space and time?

Comment: String theory is a relativistic theory built on a Euclidean pre-metric. They do a few things which they claim allows them to extract generally relativistic objects from that (like quantum black holes), but to be honest, I wouldn't buy the hype. Those are toy models which haven't delivered anything tangible. It is, by the way, important to remember that string theory was originally invented as a theory of the strong force and has only morphed to a candidate theory for a TOE after it couldn't even explain that!